# ParseError: XML or text declaration not at start of entity: line 2, column 0" using Python Element Tree

Tags: python, xml

I need to iterate over more than 100 xml files without getting this error: " ParseError: XML or text declaration not at start of entity: line 2, column 0". How can I do this? For now, I've done:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os

file_1 = ' '.join([x for x in os.listdir() if x.endswith('xml')])
utterances = []

for filename in file_1.split():
with open(filename, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as content:
    tree = ET.parse(content)
    root = tree.getroot()
    for y in root.iter('UNIT'):
        utterances.append(y.text)
```

Comment: do `ET.fromstring(content)`

Comment: If I do  tree = ET.fromstring(content) I get the error: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not '_io.TextIOWrapper'

Comment: do `ET.fromstring(content.read())` OR `ET.parse(filename)`

Comment: Unfortunally, it gives me the same error. It seems I need to remove whitespaces in some place of some xml I have. I appreciate your help, anyway.

Comment: What do you want to do with the invalid XML files? Simply ignore them? Whatever you do, you need to look at the process that generated the bad XML, and fix it so it doesn't happen again.

Comment: I didn't want to ignore them, Michael. They are all data for a research corpus. I'm working on finding how can I locate the bad ones and study their data structure.